# Help understanding how to make a bar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use the [bar_geom](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html) function of ggplot2, but I can't understand how to use it. I've made a small sample of my code to show what I am trying to do:

```
library(ggplot2)

# sample data
sampleData = data.frame( 
 v1=c('a','b','c','d','e', 'f','g', 'h', 'i','j'), 
 v2=c(1:10)     
)    
sampleData$Names = data.frame( Names = paste(sampleData$v1, sampleData$v2, sep="") )    
sampleData$Values = c(1:10)

# make plot
x = sampleData$Values
y = sampleData$Names 

qplot(      
    x, y, data = sampleData,
    geom="bar"  
)
```

I want `sampleData$Names` to be on the x-axis of my graph, labeling each bar and and `sampleData$Values` to scale the bar height. I want the y-axis to be specified as a range. I realize that I don't understand how ggplot2 functions as this small example does not work, yet my other example is generating a plot but I cannot specify a y-range as it considers the variables to be categorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qplot` expects column names within the `sampleData` data-frame, and your code where you set the 'Names' column to a data-frame is also strange. The following simpler version works:

```
sampleData = data.frame( 
 v1=c('a','b','c','d','e', 'f','g', 'h', 'i','j'), 
 v2=c(1:10)     
)

sampleData = transform( sampleData, Names = paste(v1, v2, sep=''))

qplot(   Names, v2, data = sampleData,    geom="bar"  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm still unclear about one aspect of this. If I set ylim=range(1,20), it won't plot. Why does this happen? Is it not possible to set the y-range in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

Another quick plot with the same results as pchalasani got is with

```
qplot(v1, v2, geom = "bar", stat = "identity", data = sampleData)
```

Pay special attention to the argument `stat`.